# encryption and writing to file

Tags: python, encryption

So heres the deal.

I have some data. It is so arranged that each line consists of one record. And each record consists of 4 items:

1. username
2. account name
3. password
4. remarks

These records are separated by `:`

So a sample record would look like:

`un0:ac0:password0:linkedtoemail1`

Now, when the application is closed, I encrypt all the data using ARC4 and then write it to a file. And delete the plaintext file.

```
filin = open('file','r')
separator = '\n'
filout = open('temp','w')

for i in filin:

    b = ARC4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt(i)

    filout.write(b + separator)
```

While writing I add a `\n` between two records. But when decrypting it again, I use : 
`for i in filin` where filin is the filestream object. Now when some text gets encrypted then a `\n` character is a part of the enrypted string. So when I decrypt I get results that I don't want.

**Please** tell me if there is a better way to do this. What separator should I use between two records after I have encrypted the records? And how should I detect this separator when I am decrypting the data? Kindly post the code for whatever solution you are suggesting.

I am using Python 2.7 on a Linux Mint machine.

Comment: One of the tricks, is when encrypting, write the length of the encryption before you write the encryption. Then when decrypting, you first encounter a number, then you know how many characters you have to read, then you read another number, ...

Comment: downvoter: can you please tell me a reason as to why this question has recieved a downvote?

Comment: can `filin` be read entirely into the memory?

Comment: yeah. that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents are to put your userdata into a dictionary and encode it using json, which you then encrypt.

It will save you the "looking for a terminator" hassle and the json encoding function will take care of any neccessary escaping also.

Comment: but how will JSON be equal to encryption??

Comment: it will not. i wrote that you should encrypt the json string.

Comment: I think I am gonna go with your answer. Because I simply love the way it is done! I am just trying out the code. WIll accept your answer most probably.

Comment: works like a charm!! thank you so much!!! I have been going crazy over this.... thank you so so so much!!! this completes my application!!

Comment: I think this is a pretty good way to solve a nonexistent problem.

Comment: Now all you need to worry about is what happens if your program crashes and leaves the userdata lying around unencrypted. :)

Comment: In general, implementing your own encryption scheme is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt the record seperator too, into a binary file.

There should not be any seperator in the raw encrypted file, even if you could have escaped them (which you can't do easily)

Assuming data will fit easily in memory, it might be something like that:

```
with open('file') as filin:
    data = filin.read()

from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4 # a better cipher may fit here too
with open('temp','wb') as filout:
    b = ARC4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt(data)
    filout.write(b)
```

I am not a security expert, so I don't know how safe it is. I believe it is safer than what you tried in your question, anyway.

```
with open('temp','rb') as filin:
    data = ARC4.new('0123456789123456').decrypt(filin.read())
```

Comment: @GungFoo what? I am thinking of how to do it; I am not sure how, and I don't want to post bad code. But I *am* pretty sure this is the right way (and I will be happy to be corrected on this).

Comment: @Elazar Yes that's obviously the right way to do it. Basically the entire "file" should be encrypted: `ARC4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt('\n'.join(fillin))`. From a security standpoint though, this is probably missing an appropriate encryption mode, IV...

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: I don't think actual security is the main point. If he hard codes his seed in his python source...

Comment: @Elazar : and how do i decrypt the data??

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I thought about the encryption mode too. It sounds more appropriate.

Comment: @Elazar: I really gotta go with Gung Foo. The solution that Gung Foo gave is elegant... And yours is too.. But I understand his solution better..!! But thanks anyway...!

Answer (score -1):

You could first write the length of the next encrypted record.

```
filin = open('file','r')
separator = '\n'
filout = open('temp','w')

for i in filin:

    b = ARC4.new('0123456789123456').encrypt(i)

    filout.write(b.len() + separator)
    filout.write(b)
```

Then on reading, first read the number, then read as many characters as the number indicates.

Comment: if you have the length, you don't need the seperator.

Comment: reading is just `n = int(filin.readline())`, then you have the number. Next, use `filin.read(n)`.

Comment: @Elazar: We need the length of the int, in case the encryption would start with a digit. Unless we give that int a fixed length.

Comment: I believe you should use fixed length indeed. Anyway, this scheme feels vulnerable.